# Problem with dlib installation with pip in python

Tags: python, pip

I already installed the wheel and cmake, but I still get this:

```
C:\Users>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.20.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-6oymfrau'
       cwd: C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\
  Complete output (63 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28806.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28806.0
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe (found version "3.8.3")
  CMake Error at C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
    Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
    C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\asama\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jba9eumt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\
    Complete output (65 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.8'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28806.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.26.28806.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe (found version "3.8.3")
    CMake Error at C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
      C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/asama/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-ac1wmqw_/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.8/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\dlib\setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\asama\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\asama\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ac1wmqw_\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\asama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-jba9eumt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\asama\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

pip install the wheel from cmd if you have 64 bit Windows System. And also try to downgrade to Python 3.6.4 (in the latest version it doesn't seem to work!)

```
pip install https://github.com/aminPial/Face-Recognition-App/blob/master/dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

If you want to install for 32 bit then you might want to check for 32-bit specific wheel from unofficial repository.

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure what the root cause of error even was. I have tried your suggestion but now I get this error: 
C:\>py -m pip install https://github.com/aminPial/Face-Recognition-App/blob/master/dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: can you please tell the OS you are using? you have to run specific wheel for specific OS configuration like 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: 64 bit windows 10

Comment: i also had 64 bit WIN10. Can't really understand what is happening!:(

Comment: you may want to try https://github.com/charlielito/install-dlib-python-windows.

Comment: Should I try to downgrade pip, phyton or something else?

Comment: are you using python 3.6.10? try to downgrade it to 3.6.4 . I have 3.6.4 installed and it works. I would better suggest you to leave windows installation, and just do a linux installation in WSL(Windows subsytem linux). Install WSL and you won't run in any issues next time with linux based py module's in windows.

Comment: I downgraded it to 3.6.4 and now it works! Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: my pleasure, mate:)